# Using VBA to measure and size exhibits in Excel for presentation

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel tables must fit on a single page at a given fixed scale when I print it to PDF.  I use VBA to run through all rows on the exhibit, measure their combined height with this method:

Tot_Rows = Tot_Rows + .Rows(i).RowHeight.

My exhibit fits on the same PDF printed page when the total is no more than 725 points.  The problem is when I open the same file the next day, the total acceptable height changes up or down.  Nothing changes in the file; no one else is using it, but I do work with other files in the interim.  I have to reset the total and reformat exhibits almost every time.

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Thank you,
M

Answer (score 0):

- `File` > `Print` > `Fit Sheet on One Page` will shrink the printout to fit the page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I am not looking for a workaround.  I need to understand why page height is unstable.

Comment: Dd you create pdf file with SaveAs or pdf printer?